# Ruby - Convert Array with pipe delimited values to an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

How do I make this:

```
["ford|white", "honda|blue"]
```

Into this:

```
[{'make'=>'ford', 'color'=>'white'}, {'make'=>'honda', 'color'=>'blue'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
["ford|white", "honda|blue"].collect do |str|
  ary = str.split('|')
  { 'make' => ary[0], 'color' => ary[1] }
end
```

gives me

```
[{"color"=>"white", "make"=>"ford"}, {"color"=>"blue", "make"=>"honda"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Without thought:

```
 > l = ["ford|white", "honda|blue"]
 > m = l.collect { |m| make, color = m.split('|'); { make: make, color: color } }
=> [{:make=>"ford", :color=>"white"}, {:make=>"honda", :color=>"blue"}]
```

(Using symbols for keys, generally recommended, IMO.)

Answer (score 2):

```
input = ["ford|white", "honda|blue"]
input.map do |car|
  Hash[ %w(make color).zip car.split('|') ]
end
=> [{"make"=>"ford", "color"=>"white"}, {"make"=>"honda", "color"=>"blue"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
yourarray = ["ford|white", "honda|blue"]
yourhash = yourarray.map­ {|x| y = x.spl­it('|'); {"mak­e" => y[0],­ "colo­r" => y[1]}­}
```

Comment: the solution above is perhaps prettier.